# Morris JS Chart not displaying data starting with first 3 digits as 0

Tags: javascript, linechart, morris.js

I am working on a graph that should display column `date` and column `absolute_value` retrieved from the database shown below. While date is working fine, but for some reason the values starting with 0s in the column absolute_values are not displaying at all. They are being replaced and displayed randomly(or not) by other numbers not starting with 0s.

```
| date                | absolute_value |
| ------------------- | -------------- | 
| 2023-10-29 18:12:11 | 00027424       |
| 2023-10-29 18:12:11 | 00027465       | 
| 2023-10-29 18:12:11 | 00021236       |
| 2023-10-29 18:12:11 | 00083476       |
```

This is the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  new Morris.Area({
    element: 'chart4',
    data: [{
      period: '2023-10-29 18:12:11',
      absolute_value: 00027424

    }, {
      period: '2023-10-29 18:12:11',
      absolute_value: 00027465

    }, {
      period: '2023-10-29 18:12:11',
      absolute_value: 00021236

    }, {
      period: '2023-10-29 18:12:11',
      absolute_value: 00083476
    }],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['absolute_value'],
    labels: ['absolute_value'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    pointSize: 3,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    pointStrokeColors: ['#2cbfb7', '#98c932', '#2cbfb7'],
    behaveLikeLine: true,
    gridLineColor: '#eeeeee',
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColors: ['#2cbfb7', '#98c932', '#2cbfb7'],
    resize: true

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<div id="chart4"></div>
```

This is the graph that I got after my query was echoed. For eg, the value `00027424` is being displayed as `27,581`on the graph.

[image: graph]

On the Database, the query is returning the correct values. Why is this happening? Are the numbers being formatted for this type of digits?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click [edit] and then replace the PHP var with relevant example data and add the relevant HTMLL and frameworks from CDN in a [mcve]

Comment: What does it mean, absolute value? The cart is not going to show you the ascii string value - it wants to show a number. 27,581 is 27581 in US formatted "thousand separator is comma" - here is a post https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/617

Comment: `absolute_values` is just a column name on my database.

Comment: So please show example data in the format Morris expects by updating the snippet I made you

Comment: I edited the snippet.

Comment: But not in a very useful manner. I made you a [mcve]. I had of course to change the key to absolute_value instead of absolute_values. So I ask again. Is 00027424 the same as 27424?

Comment: Thank you for editing the snippet. I'm learning. No, 00027424 is not the same as 27424.

Comment: So what IS it. YOU know what you are doing, WE do NOT know what you are doing. Why is it not the same and what are your expectations and expected graph? All is at the same time so you will not get a line

Comment: When I insert  00027424 in my database, I expect it to display as 00027424 on the graph as well.

Comment: That will not happen unless you change the labels.

Comment: change it to what?

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: Did you see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77388962/295783) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers are seen as OCTAL when the OBJECT itself is parsed by the JavaScript interpreter. You need to send them as strings.

Then you need to assign the hoverCallback to show the original string

Here is a working script

```js
const displayValues = [];
const data = [{
  period: '2023-10-29 17:12:11',
  absolute_value: '00027424'

}, {
  period: '2023-10-29 18:12:11',
  absolute_value: '00027465'

}, {
  period: '2023-10-29 19:12:11',
  absolute_value: '00021236'

}, {
  period: '2023-10-29 20:12:11',
  absolute_value: '00083476'
}].map(({
  period,
  absolute_value
}) => {
  displayValues.push(absolute_value);
  return {
    period,
    absolute_value: parseInt(absolute_value, 10)
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  new Morris.Area({
    hoverCallback: function(index, options, content, row) {
      var data = options.data[index];
      const $content = $(`<div>${content}</div>`); // copy the hover HTML
      $content.find(".morris-hover-point").text(`absolute_value: ${displayValues[index]}`);
      return $content.html();
    },

    element: 'chart4',
    data: data,
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['absolute_value'],
    labels: ['absolute_value'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    pointSize: 3,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    pointStrokeColors: ['#2cbfb7', '#98c932', '#2cbfb7'],
    behaveLikeLine: true,
    gridLineColor: '#eeeeee',
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColors: ['#2cbfb7', '#98c932', '#2cbfb7'],
    resize: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<div id="chart4"></div>
```

Here is an alternative where you send the values as integers and we pad them with leading 0s

```js
const displayValues = [];
const data = [{
  period: '2023-10-29 17:12:11',
  absolute_value: 27424

}, {
  period: '2023-10-29 18:12:11',
  absolute_value: 27465

}, {
  period: '2023-10-29 19:12:11',
  absolute_value: 21236

}, {
  period: '2023-10-29 20:12:11',
  absolute_value: 83476
}].map(({
  period,
  absolute_value
}) => {
  displayValues.push(String(absolute_value).padStart(8,"0"));
  return {
    period,
    absolute_value: parseInt(absolute_value, 10)
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  new Morris.Area({
    hoverCallback: function(index, options, content, row) {
      var data = options.data[index];
      const $content = $(`<div>${content}</div>`); // copy the hover HTML
      $content.find(".morris-hover-point").text(`absolute_value: ${displayValues[index]}`);
      return $content.html();
    },

    element: 'chart4',
    data: data,
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['absolute_value'],
    labels: ['absolute_value'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    pointSize: 3,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    pointStrokeColors: ['#2cbfb7', '#98c932', '#2cbfb7'],
    behaveLikeLine: true,
    gridLineColor: '#eeeeee',
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColors: ['#2cbfb7', '#98c932', '#2cbfb7'],
    resize: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<div id="chart4"></div>
```

Comment: I copied the hover HTML as follows: `const $content = $("<div class='morris-hover morris-default-style' style='left: 668.038px; top: 128px; display: none;'><div class='morris-hover-row-label'>"+row.period+"</div></div>"); `. The date is being displayed, but not the data for `absolute_value`.

Comment: Mine shows https://imgur.com/a/RlaOiqQ because I take the complete `content` as passed to the function. You need to do the same

Comment: Is this correct? 
`const $content = $("<div class='morris-hover morris-default-style' style='left: 668.038px; top: 128px; display: none;'><div class='morris-hover-row-label'>"+row.period+"</div><div class='morris-hover-point' style='color: #2cbfb7'>"+row.absolute_value+"</div></div>"); `

Comment: Does it work - it has display: none;?  But why do you not do what I do in my code which works?

Comment: When I copy your code, it shows `${content}`

Comment: You need the backticks! `\`` - it is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), not a quoted string

Comment: Oh right! Now I need to remove the sample data and echo data from the database. I replaced the sample data with this `const data = [<?php echo $chart_data7; ?>].map(({...` It does not work right now. What do I need to add?

Comment: If the data is an array, then do not wrap in an array. Remove the outer brackets and just have `const data = <?php ….. .>;

Comment: I removed the brackets but still does not echo data from the database.

Comment: You are giving tiny bits of information at a time. Is this an external JS file? Then it will not work. The javascript set by inline php vars need to be in the php file. Right click and select inspect or view-source then look at the javascript, it must be validd where you insert the php and the object needs to be prresent in the page

Comment: This script is inside  the file `index.php`. My SQL Queries have been worked out in `database.php`. I called the file `database.php` in `index.php`. I right-clicked `index.php` and view-source and obviously I cannot see the strings of array

Comment: Obviously? But then that is the problem... `const data = your array here;` is what is expected

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work. I tried this `const data = <?php echo json_encode($chart_data7)?>.map(({...` but no result. I also called a foreach after the query in `database.php` like this `$chart_data7 = array();
 foreach ($result7 as $row7) {
 $chart_data7[] = $row7;
 }`

Comment: And if you just `echo $chart_data7;` and under it `echo json_encode($chart_data7);` (I know it will break the page, but what does it echo)?

Comment: just `echo json_encode($chart_data7);` works. I did not check if there was recent data in my local database. Thank you you for your time and help!